# Macros vba to list all inaccessible network folders

Tags: excel

I have a vba code that scans a folder and its subdirectories for excel files and lists the connection strings and sql command. But my problem is my program doesn't list the inaccessible network folders that gives you the error "Access Denied." I wanna be able to list the path to the folder and indicate on the second column that the folder is inaccessible. How should I code it? I'm thinking

```
    On Error GoTo Handler
Handler:
    If Err.Number = x Then
        oRng.Value = sFDR & sItem
        oRng.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Inaccessible folder"
        Resume Next
    End If
```

But this code doesn't work. It doesn't specify the path of the 'access denied' folder at all. Instead, it puts the text "Inaccessible folder" to the next accessible excel file it sees.

Here's the code:

```
Private Const FILE_FILTER = "*.xl*"
Private Const sRootFDR = "Path" ' Root Folder

Private oFSO As Object ' For FileSystemObject
Private oRng As Range, N As Long ' Range object and Counter

Sub Main()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    N = 0
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        .UsedRange.ClearContents ' Remove previous contents
        .Range("A1:E1").Value = Array("Filename", "Connections", "Connection String", "Command Text", "Date Scanned")
        Set oRng = .Range("A2") ' Initial Cell to start storing results
    End With
    Columns("A:E").Select
    With Selection
        .WrapText = True
        .ColumnWidth = 45
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    End With
    ListFolder sRootFDR
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Set oRng = Nothing
    Set oFSO = Nothing
    Columns.AutoFit
    MsgBox N & " Excel files has been checked for connections."
End Sub

Private Sub ListFolder(ByVal sFDR As String)
    Dim oFDR As Object
    ' List the files of this Directory
    ListFiles sFDR, FILE_FILTER
    ' Recurse into each Sub Folder
    On Error GoTo Handler
Handler:
    If Err.Number = 5 Then
        oRng.Value = sFDR & sItem
        oRng.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Inaccessible folder"
        Resume Next
    End If
    For Each oFDR In oFSO.GetFolder(sFDR).SubFolders
    ListFolder oFDR.Path & "\" ' Need '\' to ensure the file filter works
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub ListFiles(ByVal sFDR As String, ByVal sFilter As String)
    Dim sItem As String
    On Error GoTo Handler
Handler:
    If Err.Number = 52 Then
        oRng.Value = sFDR & sItem
        oRng.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Inaccessible folder"
        Resume Next
    End If
    sItem = Dir(sFDR & sFilter)
    Do Until sItem = ""
        N = N + 1 ' Increment Counter
        oRng.Value = sFDR & sItem
        CheckFileConnections oRng.Value ' Call Sub to Check the Connection settings
        oRng.Offset(0, 4) = Now
        Set oRng = oRng.Offset(1) ' Move Range object to next cell below
        sItem = Dir
    Loop
End Sub

Private Sub CheckFileConnections(ByVal sFile As String)
    Dim oWB As Workbook, oConn As WorkbookConnection
    Dim sConn As String, sCMD As String
    Dim ConnectionNumber As Integer
    ConnectionNumber = 1
    Application.StatusBar = "Opening workbook: " & sFile
    On Error Resume Next
    Set oWB = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=sFile, ReadOnly:=True, UpdateLinks:=False, Password:=userpass)
    If Err.Number > 0 Then
        oRng.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Password protected file"
    Else
    With oWB
        For Each oConn In .Connections
            If Len(sConn) > 0 Then sConn = sConn & vbLf
            If Len(sCMD) > 0 Then sCMD = sCMD & vbLf
            sConn = sConn & oConn.ODBCConnection.Connection
            sCMD = sCMD & oConn.ODBCConnection.CommandText

            oRng.Offset(0, 1).Value = ConnectionNumber ' 1 column to right (B)
            oRng.Offset(0, 2).Value = oConn.ODBCConnection.Connection ' 2 columns to right (C)
            oRng.Offset(0, 3).Value = oConn.ODBCConnection.CommandText ' 3 columns to right (D)
            ConnectionNumber = ConnectionNumber + 1
            Set oRng = oRng.Offset(1) ' Move Range object to next cell below
        Next
    End With
    End If
    oWB.Close False ' Close without saving
    Set oWB = Nothing
    Application.StatusBar = False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hum, I tried debugging your code and found the following.

Your error handlers are coded a bit goofy.  If the handler gets triggered, yet the error code is NOT the one you are testing for, then you will re-invoke the loop from start.  It would be more clean to code them as:

```
Private Sub ListFolder(ByVal sFDR As String)
    Dim oFDR As Object, lFDR As Object
    ' List the files of this Directory
    ListFiles sFDR, FILE_FILTER
    ' Recurse into each Sub Folder
    On Error GoTo Handler
    For Each oFDR In oFSO.GetFolder(sFDR).SubFolders
        ListFolder oFDR.Path & "\" ' Need '\' to ensure the file filter works
    Next
    Exit Sub
Handler:
    If Err.Number = 70 Then
        oRng.Value = sFDR
        oRng.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Inaccessible folder - access denied"

    End If
    Resume Next
End Sub
```

This ensures you perform a Resume Next for all errors that trigger the handler, not just the one error you are looking for.  I know for the ListFiles() sub, that re-entrance into the loop should work properly, but still it is bad form.  And that code format does not work for the ListFolder() sub as it causes hard aborts.

When I changed your ListFolder as shown (and changed Err.Number checked for to 70), you code seems to work for me.  I made both inaccessible files and folders, and the proper error tag was shown with the proper file names and directory names that I made inaccessible.